# OR applications in medicine

Tags: optimization

Read this [article](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4296668/) on potential application of Markov Decision Process in decision making process of patient evaluation schedule.
Does anyone know or have experience in application of such OR techniques in medicine? 
I am aware of application of optimization in logistics, scheduling. Looking for applications directly in medical decisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two colleagues and I published a paper[1] on an optimization model for creating patient panels for primary care providers. A patient panel is the set of patients seeing a particular provider at a particular location. The model takes into account doctor availability, how much time each doctor allocates to each type of appointment, the needs of the patients, patient preferences (for instance, a patient might want a female doctor) and location, and includes options for hiring new staff.

**Addendum**: There is also a substantial body of work on the use of integer programming models to design radiotherapy treatments in oncology. It's been a while since I saw any of it, but I believe decision variables included positioning of emitters and power/duration of radiation bursts. Eva K. Lee[2], formerly of Georgia Institute of Technology, was (I believe) a pioneer in that area.

[1] Harrington, William, Paul A. Rubin and Lihui Bai. “An optimization approach to panel size management”. In: *Operations Research for Health Care* **31**, article 100313. ISSN: 2211-6923. DOI: https://doi.org/10.1016/j.orhc.2021.100313.

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eva_K._Lee

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout work from [Nadia Lahrichi](https://scholar.google.com/citations?hl=fr&user=msbeB7oAAAAJ), she is an OR expert and has written many papers with healthcare applications such as:

- [A patient assignment algorithm for home care services](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=fr&user=msbeB7oAAAAJ&citation_for_view=msbeB7oAAAAJ:roLk4NBRz8UC)
- [The nurse scheduling problem in real-life](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=fr&user=msbeB7oAAAAJ&citation_for_view=msbeB7oAAAAJ:hqOjcs7Dif8C)
- [Online stochastic optimization of radiotherapy patient scheduling](https://scholar.google.com/citations?view_op=view_citation&hl=fr&user=msbeB7oAAAAJ&citation_for_view=msbeB7oAAAAJ:_kc_bZDykSQC)

Comment: Thanks for the guides.